# How can I remove extra whitespace that UIWebView adds to bottom of document?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, rtf

I want the instructions page of my app to look decent and be easy (for developers) to edit. Attributed text seems too complicated to use and alter, so I wrote an RTF file with TextEdit, and had my program read it into a UIWebView the way [Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html):

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

// Calling -loadDocument:inView:
[self loadDocument:@"instructions.rtf" inView:self.myWebview];
```

(One modification included.)

It looks great and my document fits nicely inside the WebView! But for some reason the WebView adds a lot of whitespace at the bottom (1/3rd the height of the text!), making the scroll bar necessary. (I'd like to omit the scroll bar unless the length of the actual text warrants it.)

Does anyone know where the whitespace comes from and how I can remove it

Comment: did you ever find a solution

Comment: @Geet, no. And the question lost its relevance for me.